# Можно ли задать transition для ::before

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы у элемента `::before` при наведении плавно менялась высота. `transition` не работает. Есть способы, чтобы все работало без JS?

```css
.card1 {
  width: 239px;
  height: 360px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(42, 42, 42);
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 239px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.card1:hover::before {
  height: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="place">
  <div class="card1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно задать первоначальную высоту `0px`.

```css
.card1 {
  width: 239px;
  height: 360px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(42, 42, 42);
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 239px;
  height: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: height 0.4s linear;
}

.card1:hover::before {
  height: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="place">
  <div class="card1"></div>
</div>
```